# In voice call other side is unable to hear me

Tags: linux, skype, kubuntu, voice-chat

I'm experiencing problem in voice calling in Linux since last week. It is happening with skype, Google Talk and Pidgin. I think there is something wrong with pulse audio or might be some drive settings.

I'm using Kubuntu 11.04 on my laptop. I'm able to hear voice from other side but other side is unable to hear me. Skype call testing service is also not working. 
I have tried voice call using

- Skype version 2.2 beta.
- Google talk plugin 2.2 and 2.3 (updated last night).
- Pidgin (stock version).

but same problem happens with all three.

On same machine and same microphone, I'm able to make call in windows.

Update 1 : I found the reason for the problem. Kmix is not showing anything is capturing device tab. I Kde control panel-> sound, it showing Audio recoding device as disabled. Now how I can enable it.

Comment: Have you tried using a stand-alone sound recorder (Audacity comes to mind) to verify that the microphone audio hasn't been muted or something equally silly?

Comment: I did not tried stand alone recorder, but I have checked microphone settings.

Comment: So try another program!

Comment: This is related to device settings, as this is happening with all three apps.